# Is there a natural way to say "the purpose is that I want to work with you"?

Tags: expressions

I'd like to say to boss in the interview like this

> the purpose is that I want to work with you.

How to get a natural expression?
I'm not sure whether it makes a sense or not.

Also,

> I think the your new device has a lot of possibilities to achieve more responsibilities of mine

Is this making a sense? If not, how to get a natural expression?

Answer (score 1):

> the purpose is that I want to work with you

This seems fine, though more context would be helpful. Some suggestions are

1. The **reason** is that I want to work with you.
2. (I applied to this position) **because** I want to work with you.

> I think the your new device has a lot of possibilities to achieve more responsibilities of mine

I have some concerns.

1. Since you have one device, if it just has one function, but that function has many applications, then I would consider using "possibility".
2. *Responsibilities* can imply a sense of long-term tasks. In such a case, I don't think someone "achieves" their responsibility. It is might be better to use words that suggest that the devices *helps* with your responsibilities.
3. It is possible to end with *of mine*, but if you can squeeze the word *my* in the sentence instead, that might sound more natural.
4. There is also the matter of whether the device *helps* achieve the goal or does it without you. If the device can take care of your responsibilities without you, then you might use the phrase "relieve me".

Some possibilities are:

> 1. I think your new device has the **possibility** to help [me] with **my** responsibilities.
> 2. I think your new device has the **potential** to help [me] with **my** responsibilities.
> 3. I think your new device has the **potential** to **relieve me** of my responsibilities.

Comment: Thanks, the device is one device but the device's function has a lot of possibilities to application.

Comment: How about this? " I think your new device has a lot of possibilities and it leads me to wok with your role and responsibities.

Comment: No, not quite. That sounds a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to work with *someone*, the usual expression is

> I would like to work with you *(on your project)*

If you want to talk about the project they are working on, you could use

> I think your project is very interesting and exciting and will generate many opportunities for clients as well as for the people working on it.

Usually the fact that you would like higher levels of responsibility (and compensation) is implied, but will depend on what skills you have to offer to the project.

Comment: can you a little bit write more easier?